# pH of meteorite

Tags: meteor, meteor-shower

When a meteorite shower strikes a water body, what will be the pH of the water after the strike.

Will it always be $<7$

or

Will it always be $>7$

or

Will it always be $=7$

or

The answer varies from case to case

Answer (score 2):

Meteorites are rocks, and rocks are normally quite insoluble. When an insoluble body is mixed with water the pH of the water isn't changed.#

Meteorites contain quite a lot of various metallic oxides, which are bases. This includes magnesium oxide which can dissolve a little, and is Alkali. The energy released by a large impact could also cause some nitrogen oxides to form from the atmosphere (which are acidic).

However these are small effects. The pH of the water is little changed. The seas are big, and any effect is soon diluted.

Comment: Well, he didn't specify **which** water body :-)